# bash - append specific column of multiple files to a new file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, paste

I have many files in a folder. All files have same format:

file A:

```
090722 12:15 - 12:45  2342
090722 12:30 - 13:00  73
090722 12:45 - 13:15  543
...
```

file B:

```
090722 12:15 - 12:45  874
090722 12:30 - 13:00  32
090722 12:45 - 13:15  2543
...
```

and so on ... The first part is always the same and should print only once a time.
Would like to get an ouput like this:

```
090722 12:15 - 12:45  2342 874  values_fileC values_fileD ...
090722 12:30 - 13:00  73   32   values_fileC values_fileD ...
090722 12:45 - 13:15  543  2543 values_fileC values_fileD ...
...
```

I've tried something like:

```
paste files* > final.txt
```

That work's fine, but don't know how to add only the columns with the values from the files?

Some ideas failed:

```
paste files* | awk '{ print $5 }' > final.txt
for f in files*; do cat $f | awk '{print $5}'; done > final.txt
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are these `AAAAAA HH:MM - HH:MM`? Are they always the same at every line of all your files? Please provide a simple example with actual input files and the corresponding expected output file. What does not work with what you tried? _Ideas failed_ does nor give any clue about what you want.

Comment: sorry, i have updated this! first column is a constant number, second column is a time span.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk -F' ' '{a[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4]=a[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4]"\t"$5}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' file*
```

Output:

```
090722 12:15 - 12:45    2342    874
090722 12:45 - 13:15    543     2543
090722 12:30 - 13:00    73      32
```

**Update:**

```
awk -F' ' '{a[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4]=a[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4]"\t"$5}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' file* | sort -t " " -k 2,2n
```

Output:

```
090722 12:15 - 12:45    2342    874
090722 12:30 - 13:00    73      32
090722 12:45 - 13:15    543     2543
```

Comment: it seems, that the first data column is this from last file in list. can i change the order?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use awk to combine the fields:

```
awk '{ 
  key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; if (NR == FNR) a[NR] = key; out[key] = out[key] FS $5
} END { for(i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) print a[i], out[a[i]] }' file*
```

Laid out as a script (which you could run with `awk -f script.awk file*`):

```
{ 
    key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 # build key using first four fields
    if (NR == FNR) a[NR] = key # record order in which fields appear
    out[key] = out[key] FS $5  # build output array using fifth field
} 

END { 
    # loop through and print keys, values
    for(i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) print a[i], out[a[i]] 
}
```

This makes the assumption that each file contains the same number of records.

I can think of two ways to achieve a fixed width output. If you're sure that the values being combined will only vary in length within the range of one tab stop, then the simplest solution is just to use a `\t` instead of `FS` in this line:

```
out[key] = out[key] "\t" $5  # build output array using fifth field
```

Otherwise you could use `sprintf` to pad each value to a length of your choice:

```
out[key] = out[key] sprintf("%6s", $5)
```

You can left-align the fields using `-6` instead of `6`.

Comment: thanks. is there a chance to reserve a min_width of character for each print? the output is tattered.

Comment: I've added to my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Note that only C shells have problems with multi-line string arguments.  Bourne-shell derivatives can use a single-quoted (or double-quoted) string that spreads over multiple lines.  There's no need to smush everything onto a single line.  "One-liner" is a pejorative term except in the APL community.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm aware of the fact that strings can span multiple lines :) my intention was to provide something easy to copy and run. As for the second part of your comment, I'd say that's pretty opinionated. Personally, I'd probably go with the script for readability/maintainability but if it's just a quick one-off script then I don't see the harm in a one-liner.